# Value of a perfect hedge

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, mathematics, finance-mathematics

**Background Information:**

The price of a portfolio at time $t$ ($t = 0 ,1$) is $$V_t(\pi) = \phi S_t + \psi B_t$$
The portfolio $\pi$ is a perfect hedge for the claim $X$ if $V_1(\pi) = X$ a.s. as random variables.

Given claim $X$, to have a perfect hedge then $\phi$ and $\psi$ must satisfy 
\begin{equation}
\phi S_1(u) + \psi B_1 = X(u)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\phi S_1(d) + \psi B_2 = X(d)
\end{equation}
We have solving for this that 
$$\phi = \frac{X(u) - X(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)}$$
$$\psi = B_1^{-1}(X(u) - \phi S_1(u)) = B_1^{-1}(X(d) - S_1(d))$$
Thus the resulting value of $X$ at $t=0$ is $$V_0(X) = V_0(\pi) = \phi S_0 + \psi B_0$$

**Question:**

> Let $\beta = B_0 B_1^{-1}$ be the discount factor. Show that
>
> $$V_0(X) = \beta\left[\left(\frac{\beta^{-1}S_0 - S_1(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)}\right)X(u) + \left(\frac{S_1(u) - \beta^{-1}S_0}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)}\right)X(d)\right]$$

I have tried this three times now and I still not getting the result what I do is this if you want to see my attempted work let me know. Otherwise it would be great if someone could give me a good start to this. There must be something that I am not seeing in regards to some algebra trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the values for $\phi$ and $\psi$ that you have derived, 
\begin{align*}
V_0(X) &= \phi S_0 + \psi B_0\\
&= \frac{X(u) - X(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)} S_0 + B_1^{-1}\left(X(u) - \frac{X(u) - X(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)}S_1(u)\right) B_0\\
&=\beta\left(\frac{X(u) - X(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)} \beta^{-1}S_0 + \frac{X(d) S_1(u) - X(u)S_1(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)} \right)\\
&=\beta\left(\frac{\beta^{-1}S_0 - S_1(d)}{S_1(u) - S_1(d)} X(u) + \frac{S_1(u) - \beta^{-1}S_0 }{S_1(u) - S_1(d)} X(d)\right).
\end{align*}
What you need is to combine terms with $X(u)$ together, and likewise for terms with $X(d)$.

Comment: I am a little lost on your second to last step to the last step, could you add a little more detail in?

Comment: try to put all $X(u)$ terms together and all $X(d)$ terms together and see what you can get. It is just algebra, please try.

Comment: sorry to keep bothering you but I have a new question that is tied to this one